# Installing PHP GD on my Windows 7 with Apache

Tags: php, apache, installation, gd

**For the life of me I cannot get GD installed in my Windows 7 PHP build.** This is what I have done:

My path is C:/webserver/php/php.ini

Naturally, GD is commented out in my php.ini file. (;extension=php_gd2.dll)

1. I remove the semicolon in front of extension
2. save php.ini
3. copy php_gd2.dll from .../php/ext/ and
4. paste it in the /php/ folder
5. Restart Apache.

Everything everywhere says that should work but it does not.

running phpinfo(); shows me that the path to php.ini is correct and that GD is ***still not installed***.

What am I doing wrong? I am at my wit's end.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK you have to leave php_gd2.dll in .../ext/ folder.

Comment: **Great job. You led me to it:** Knowing the .dll needed to stay in the \ext\ folder helped me see that all the other extensions not commented out in php.ini used the absolute path, not the relative paths. So I just edited the php.ini file line with `extension=php_gd2.dll` to say `extension="c:\webserver\php\ext\php_gd2.dll"` and deleted the copy of php_gd2.dll from the \php\ folder, keeping the original copy in the \php\ext\ folder and **...now it works!**  Thank you. Also I heard AFAIK for the first time (explained by urbandictionary), so thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To enable .php lib" index for Apache24.
Go to your Apache24\conf . Open httpd.conf file then search
 paste following code

```
<IfModule mime_module>
AddType text/html .shtml
    AddType text/html .php .phps

</IfModule>
```